# I cant' add elements to Binary Search Tree correctly in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I want to create binary search tree which I get the elements (words) from a text file. But, my compare-function always compares the two same words. When I call the insert function, root and data have the same value. Therefore the insert function always adds the elements to left child. I don't understand why.

But maybe it is about the do-while loop.

When I execute it, the output is the last word of the file a hundred times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

struct n
{
char *data;
struct n *left;
struct n*right;
};

typedef struct n node;

void in_Order(node *root)
{
if (root == NULL)
    return;

printf("%s ", root->data); 
in_Order(root->left);
in_Order(root->right);
}

int compare(node *root, char data[14])
{
if (strcmp(root->data, data) <= 0)
    return 1;
else return -1;
}
node *getNewNode(char *data)
{
node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
newNode->left = NULL;
newNode->right = NULL;
newNode->data = data;
return newNode;
}

node *insert(node *root, char *data)
{
if (root == NULL)
{
    root = getNewNode(data);
    return root;
}
if (compare(root,data) == 1)
    root->left = insert(root->left, data);
else 
    root->right = insert(root->right, data);

return root;

}

int main()
{
node *root = NULL;
FILE *fptr = fopen("File.txt", "r");
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);
int status;

do
{
    fscanf(fptr, "%s", buffer);
    root = insert(root, buffer);
} while (status = fgetc(fptr) != EOF);

in_Order(root);

}
```

Comment: You are inserting the same buffer. It needs to create a copy. E.g `newNode->data = data;` --> `newNode->data = strdup(data);`

Comment: Thank you I got my answer and I looked strdup function. But how does my code work? Buffer always changing. For example, first it's value is "When". After first execution of insert function, buffer's value is changing and new value of it "was". In main function,(in while loop), root->data and buffer 's value is "was". I am curious about why root->data's value is changing before call the insert function.  I am sorry I am posting in my mobile phone.

Comment: `data` point to `&buffer[0]`. always same. Even though the contents of the buffer change, the buffer itself is the same.

Comment: Yes now I noticed it,thanks 